# Custom QGraphicsRectItem cannot receive mouseMoveEvent

Tags: qt

Item.h:

```
class Item:public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    Item(const QRectF & rect, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0);
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);
    void ​mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);
    ~Item();
};
```

Item.cpp:

```
Item::Item(const QRectF & rect, QGraphicsItem * parent)
    :QGraphicsRectItem(rect, parent)
{
}
void Item::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event){
    qDebug("press");
    QGraphicsRectItem::mousePressEvent(event);
    event->accept();
}
void Item::​mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event){
    qDebug("move");
}
Item::~Item()
{
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "QGraphicsView"
#include "QGraphicsScene"
#include "item.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
 //   MainWindow w;
 //   w.show();

    auto item = new Item(QRectF(QPointF(),QSize(100,150)));

    auto scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->addItem(item);

    auto view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->setMinimumSize(QSize(800,600));
    view->scene()->setSceneRect(QRectF(QPointF(),view->size()));
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have read the doc about QGraphicsItem::​mousePressEvent, which says "If you do reimplement this function, event will by default be accepted (see QEvent::accept()), and this item is then the mouse grabber. This allows the item to receive future move, release and doubleclick events." Now I have reimplemented it. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't work or that it does work?

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm curious anout how qt knows whether I have reimpletemented this function when I  keep the base implementation when reimplementing it.@thuga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the mouse event is created it is set as accepted. Depending on the flags you have set to your item, [the default `mousePressEvent` implementation](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/andyc-clone/source/d4e8dd78b047812ed6d22419649a22362cb531fd:src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp#L5967) might reject it.

In your case you are calling the default implementation which might reject the mouse press event. If that is the case, the `mouseMoveEvent` will never be called.

You should read [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq11-events.html) interesting article about events.

Comment: not work even if I call accept() at the end of my reimplementation.

Comment: @Nya Works fine for me. Calling `accept` after calling the base class implementation makes it call `mouseMoveEvent`.

Comment: What the ****. Could  you please try running my code? I'm almost crasy right now

Comment: My code is pretty much identical to yours.. only difference is in the `mousePresseEvent` I call `event->accept();` after calling the base class implementation.

Comment: Please zip your project files and send to my email: callmetsing@gmail.com . Thanks

Comment: Yours runs well on my machine. However, I haven't figure it out yet

Answer (score 0):

Enable flags to use the functionalities

```
item ->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
item ->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
item ->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a move event from the mouse without a mouse button press, you can use virtual void QGraphicsItem::hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) instead.